# Symfony 3 environment driven by url - 404 on _wdt and _profile

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I would like to drive my environment (dev, prod) by URL

```
myuser.ENV.domain (eg : foo.dev.test.com or foo.prod.test.com)
```

So I decide to do some changes in .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} mydevserver.priv?$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.(.+)\.(mydevserver.priv)?(:80)?$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=SF_USER:%1,E=SF_ENV:%2,E=SF_SERVER:%3,QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Next, I do some changes in app.php

```
<?php

ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
umask(0000);

use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$env = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'SF_ENV') ?: $_SERVER['SF_ENV'];

/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__ . '/../app/autoload.php';

if ('dev' === $env) {
    $debug = true;
    Debug::enable();
} elseif ('prod' === $env) {
    include_once __DIR__ . '/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';
    $debug = false;
} else {
    throw new \Exception('Environment Not handled');
}

$kernel = new AppKernel($env, $debug);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

When I go on the prod URL, I have the default success page of Symfony 3, without debug toolbar.

When I go on the dev URL, I have the default success page but I don't have the debug toolbar. There is a 404 error about _wdt & _profiler routes.

But, If I go on the file app_dev.php, I have the debug tool bar.

I probably miss a little thing but I can't figure out.

I did a fast test renaming app.php into index.php and remove the DirectoryIndex but it changes nothing.

If I user var_dump on my $env var, it gets the good env from environment variable SF_ENV.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what's wrong exactly but setting up a virtual host might be simpler solution providing same results.

You have all the settings needed in [Symfony virtual host](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) documentation. If you choose to go that way and you are using Apache 2.4+ follow the mod_php settings. Also this version of Apache server has replaced

> Order Allow,Deny
>           Allow from All

with:

> Require all granted

You also have youtube video tutorials on how to setup virtual hosts. Here's an example of one of my virtual hosts which I made following the above mentioned documentation, vhost for a simple symfony app for testing:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.login.com
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/symfUser/web"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/symfUser/web">
    Require all granted
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/symfUser/web/bundles">
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine Off
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Well, I have decided to do as you say. I did 2 vhosts one poiting on app_dev and the otther on app. I have my two url and it's working pretty well.